# How to solve "The payload is invalid" in Laravel 8 when the payload suddenly becomes NULL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, password-encryption

I keep getting this error when trying to decrypt a password previously encrypted:

```
The payload is invalid.
```

And this is the relevant stack trace:

```
#0 /home/improojf/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php(136): Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter->getJsonPayload(NULL)
#1 /home/improojf/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php(164): Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter->decrypt('eyJpdiI6InloT0U...', false)
#2 /home/improojf/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(261): Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter->decryptString('eyJpdiI6InloT0U...')
#3 /home/improojf/public_html/app/Models/Server.php(29): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('decryptString', Array)
#4 /home/improojf/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php(473): Server->getPasswordAttribute('eyJpdiI6InloT0U...')
```

The biggest issue here is that a string randomly becomes `NULL` in the encrypter code, which makes no sense to me.

Another issue with this, is that some records just behave ad intended.

**What do I use it for**
This is used to store passwords for smtp/pop3 servers on a database

**What I tried**
This problem is perfectly solved by not encrypting/decrypting the password, which messes up the purpose

**Does it always return error?** No, in fact there are some records that behave normally

**What are my guesses** `php artisan cache:clear` might be an option as reported elsewhere, but I think there should be another solution. So far I have (untested) the following accessor while previously I only had the second try/catch

```
public function getPasswordAttribute($value){
    try {
        return Crypt::decryptString($value);
    } catch (\Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException $e) {
        \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    }
    try {
        return Crypt::decryptString($value);
    } catch (\Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException $e) {
        if(app()->runningUnitTests())
            return $value;
        else
            throw $e;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per official documentation

> Laravel's encryption services provide a simple, convenient interface
> for encrypting and decrypting text via OpenSSL using AES-256 and
> AES-128 encryption.
>
> All of Laravel's encrypted values are signed using a message
> authentication code (MAC) so that their underlying value can not be
> modified or tampered with once

**Before using Laravel's encrypter, you must set the key configuration option in your config/app.php configuration file.**

It means encryption decryption depends on `app key` value.If new app key generated then old encrypted value will not work with new app key

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/encryption

**Updated**

The issue is encrypted value was  stored partially in database table due to data type varchar(191).

So better to change data type `varchar(191)` to `longtext` or `text`

Comment: I have an `APP_KEY` in my `.env` file and, as specified before, it works for some records in the database.... I don't think that's the problem

Comment: @clod986. as i mentioned if you change app key then previously generated encryptions are not decrypted in new key.that usually append with me,not sure is that the same case in your scenario

Comment: Nope, this happens with newly generated encrypted strings, so it basically crashes after saving because it cannot load

Comment: oh okay. is table column is text .may be its not storing full encrypted string

Comment: it actually is `varchar(191)`... do you think this could be the problem?

Comment: i think so .can you change once  by changing into longtext

Comment: that solved it on my local machine!!! Please write the answer so I can accept it and give you credit for it

Answer (score 0):

Use **nullable** text or longtext column

Answer (score 0):

in my case the problem wasn't the column type, but the **default $attributes value**, because the value casting in my project
it had to be of type `'encripted:collection'`

```
/**
 * The model's default values for attributes.
 *
 * @var array
 */

protected $attributes = array(
    'is_complete' => false,
    'responses' => [], //Problem was here
);
```

I have solved by removing `'responses' => [],`and defining an accessor instead:

```
public function getResponsesAttribute($value)
{
    return $value ? $value : collect();
}
```